# Setting up JNotify

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jar, jnotify

I've attached the `jnotify.jar file` in my referenced libraries (in eclipse).

An error shows up saying:

> The libraries cannot be found in "D:/Java/jre/bin"

I copied the `jnotify.dll` file to that location, and now file changes are being tracked only within my project directory and not anywhere else on my system.
How do I set it up so that file changes can be tracked from any other directory?

```
String path = "C:/Users/ansuj/Desktop/testdir";  //does not fix the issue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dll from your Java bin. the best practice is to put it next to your jar and use

```
java -jar -Djava.library.path=. something.jar
```

In Eclipse you can add -Djava.library.path=. to your JVM arguments section in the run dialog screen.